# Awk problem: an 'if column conditional' replaces the column entry!

Tags: awk, columns

I'm trying to get a grip on awk.

Suppose I have an input:

```
this header
fred blah 1 blank
fred blah 1 blank
huh blah 2 blank
fred blah 3 blank
fred blah 3 blank
```

and after I use the following awk script,

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    if ( NF <=2 ) {
            print $0
    };
    if ( NF>=3 && $3=1)
     {
            print $0
    }
}
```

I expect to get this output:

```
this header
fred blah 1 blank
fred blah 1 blank
```

But instead I get this output:

```
this header
fred blah 1 blank
fred blah 1 blank
huh blah 1 blank
fred blah 1 blank
fred blah 1 blank
```

where $3 has been turned into the condition.

Why does this happen?

And how do I tweak my awk script to give me the output that I expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not mistake

```
a = b
```

and

```
a == b
```

even with `if ( )` test, `a = b` is setting b's value to a. (even if a is `$3`).

you should write :

```
$3 == 1
```